# Unable to install virtual box guest additions on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, guest-additions

I am unable to install virtual box guest additions in Lubuntu 16.04

My following is my terminal screenshot:

[image]

When I type in terminal `./autorun.sh`

I get the following output:

```
Linux guest additions installer not found --try to start them manually.
```

Why this is happening and how to "start them manually"?

I have tried shutting down the machine, removing guestadditions.iso, restarting the machine, and reinserting the guest additions CD.

But the problem persists.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Comment: If you get permission denied, `chmod +x` it and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much but I know it :)

Comment: Then may I ask why you didn't mention you tried that in your question?

Comment: Well I did do `sudo` but I often don't mention it as it is too obvious

Answer (score 26):

I managed to solve my problem, it is pretty easy.

What I did was I opened terminal and typed:

```
apt update
apt upgrade #To install Linux headers
apt install gcc
apt install make
cd /media/"username"/VBOX*
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
reboot
```

Then I set the monitor screen resolution to mine (which is 1360x644)

Then I restarted it again.

And it is done

Comment: Thanks. Perfect and concise. I would only add that you need to either prefix each command by sudo or run sudo -i (interactive session) before executing the commands

Comment: I get a `VirtualBox Guest Additions: modprobe vboxsf failed` error, but maybe it will mean nothing after a reboot? -- Edit, yes, I re-ran the next-to-last command after rebooting and it worked with no errors. Not sure if it's necessary to do it twice, but I was reassured.

Answer (score 2):

Another issue I found where none of these solutions worked (installing Raspberry Pi Desktop):

`./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` no good

`sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` no good

`sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` SUCCESS

So it seems you sometimes have to explicitly run the vbox additions file with `sh` - otherwise it will fail with "Linux guest additions installer not found --try to start them manually."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `autorun.sh` looks for konsole, gnome-terminal, mate-terminal, or xterm, and Lubuntu has none of them installed. A simple remedy is to run

```
sudo apt install xterm gcc make
```

before inserting the guest additions Then you can double-click on `autorun.sh` in PCManFM, and the installation works as it was presumably intended.

Answer (score 0):

Typeing the following commands works for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
$ ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```